# Delphi7 IndyDownloads, unable to play video file in VLC while downloading

Tags: delphi, indy

I am using Delphi 7 with IndyDownloads component for my downlaoder. I want to play a video file which is downloading, in VLC player. When I tried to open the file, "myvideofile.avi.part" in VLC i am getting the following error.

VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///D:/MyDir/myvideofile.avi.part'. Check the log for details.

IndyDownloads using filestream, I created the filestream as follows:

```
TFileStream.Create(LocalFilename, fmCreate or fmShareDenyNone);
```

Still it did not work.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. VLC is capable of playing .temp extension. Also once the downloader completes the download, the output file will be myvideofile.avi. I want to play while downloading. I saw while downloading with firefox, we can play the .part file in VLC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Delphi are you are?  In older versions, `fmCreate` does not co-exist with other `Mode` flags.  Any additional flags you specify would simply be ignored, and `fmCreate` by itself will then create the file with exclusive rights.  That could explain why VLC cannot access the file while you still have it open.  To get around that, create and close the file first, and then reopen the file with less-restrictive rights, eg:

```
FileClose(FileCreate(LocalFilename));
... := TFileStream.Create(LocalFilename, fmOpenReadWrite or fmShareDenyNone);
```

In modern Delphi versions, `fmCreate` does now co-exist with sharing flags.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am using Delphi 7. I am trying your comment